# Authorization issues with Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I ran into a problem with Ajax: i am calling a server side function via Ajax. Nothing strange so far. The problem is that it doesn't give me back any results and while debugging, I found that it gives permission problems. I don't understand where the problem is.

CODICE AJAX

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


let parametri = { utente: user, Password: pass }

             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 url: "WebControls.aspx/CliccaBottone",
                 data: JSON.stringify(parametri),
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (i) {

                     if (i == 0) {


                         alert("Le credenziali sono errate");
                     }

                     else {

                         alert("Hai eseguito il login");
                     }

                 }
                    
              });
```

CODICE C#

```
 public partial class WebControls : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static int CliccaBottone(string utente, string Password) 
    {
        
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Credenziali WHERE Username = @User AND Pass = @Password";
        int i = 0;
       
       
        
        
        
        //VIENE APERTA LA CONNESSIONE COL DB
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["coso"].ConnectionString))
         {
               connection.Open();
            

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
            {
                SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("User", utente);
                SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter("Password", Password);
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter2);
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    i++;
                }
                 
                
           
                reader.Close();
                


            }

            
            
        }
                  return i;
    } 
}
```

}

I suspect there is an error on the server side, because the syntax written on the client side seems correct to me. But logically if an incorrect function is called that will not work. Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: what's a permission problem?

Comment: 401 error, authorization problem

Comment: Please pay attention when writing your questions, especially when selecting tags. It seems to be easy to select the C language tag instead of C# by mistake. Please [edit] your question to fix.

Comment: what happens when you make the same request without AJAX?

Comment: without ajax I handled the server side issue in C #, and it works. But I was asked to manage on the client side

Comment: Please remember that C and C# are very different languages. Please use proper language tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: yes that's right, I got confused. I apologize

Comment: so it doesn't work with AJAX, but it works without AJAX? Then you need to see what's the difference between the AJAX and non-AJAX requests.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the problem actually is, I'm looking for various solutions but nothing relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you handling credentials when connecting the the database itself? If it's pass through authentication, what credentials is your application using when accessing the database?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem finally, it was enough to set the RedirectMode parameter in off mode. From that moment on, no problem. Thank you very much.